# Can someone help fix my collision detection and restart game functions in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python so I'm struggling with coding at the moment. My collision_detection function doesn't seem to work and when I use my restart_game function I get these errors:

```
  line 120, in <module>
    restart_game()
   line 101, in restart_game
    game()
   line 106, in game
    collision_detection()
   line 86, in collision_detection
    if pig_bbox[3] > 525:
       ~~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

window = Tk()
window.title("Flappy Pig")
window.iconbitmap('flypig.ico')
screenwidth = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = window.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screenwidth / 2) - 250
y = (screenheight / 2) - 300
window.geometry(f'500x600+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=600, background="#ADD8E6")
canvas.pack()

farm_img = Image.open("farm2.png")
farmresized = farm_img.resize((600, 150))
newfarm = ImageTk.PhotoImage(farmresized)
farm = canvas.create_image(200, 450, image=newfarm)

# code to create pig
Pig_Y = 250
pig = Image.open("flypig.png")
pigresized = pig.resize((100, 100))
pig_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pigresized)
pig_item = canvas.create_image(200, Pig_Y, image=pig_img)

bgbottom = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 535, 500, 600, fill="grey", outline="grey")

topPoles = []
bottomPoles = []
poleSpeed = -1.5
lifeStatus = "alive"

def create_poles():
    x2 = randint(0, 385)
    y1 = x2 + 150
    topPoles.append(canvas.create_rectangle(470, 0, 500, x2, fill="green", outline="green"))
    bottomPoles.append(canvas.create_rectangle(470, y1, 500, 535, fill="green", outline="green"))
    window.after(2000, create_poles)  # Adjust the interval as needed

def poles_move():
    if lifeStatus == "alive":
        for i in topPoles:
            canvas.move(i, poleSpeed, 0)
        for j in bottomPoles:
            canvas.move(j, poleSpeed, 0)

    window.after(10, poles_move)


def pig_move(event):
    canvas.move(pig_item, 0, -60)


window.bind('<space>', pig_move)

def pig_fall():
    canvas.move(pig_item, 0, 4)
    window.after(20, pig_fall)

def you_died():
    global lifeStatus
    canvas.delete("all")  # Clear the canvas
    topPoles.clear()
    bottomPoles.clear()
    lifeStatus = "dead"
    deadbg = Canvas(window, width=500, height=600, background="red")
    deadbg.create_text(250, 250, text="You Died!", font=('Helvetica', '30', 'bold'))
    deadbg.create_text(250, 350, text="press x to restart", font=(20))
    deadbg.pack()


def collision_detection():
    pig_bbox = canvas.bbox(pig_item)
    for bottom_pole in bottomPoles:
        coords_bottom_pole = canvas.bbox(bottom_pole)
        if pig_bbox[0] < coords_bottom_pole[2] and pig_bbox[2] > coords_bottom_pole[0] and pig_bbox[1] < coords_bottom_pole[3] and pig_bbox[3] > coords_bottom_pole[1]:
            you_died()
    for top_pole in topPoles:
        coords_top_pole = canvas.bbox(top_pole)
        if pig_bbox[0] < coords_top_pole[2] and pig_bbox[2] > coords_top_pole[0] and pig_bbox[1] < coords_top_pole[3] and pig_bbox[3] > coords_top_pole[1]:
            you_died()
    if pig_bbox[3] > 525:
        you_died()
    if pig_bbox[1] < -100:
        pig_bbox[1] = -50

def restart_game():
    global lifeStatus
    Score = 0
    lifeStatus = "alive"
    canvas.delete("all")  # Clear the canvas
    canvas.create_image(200, 450, image=newfarm)
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 535, 500, 600, fill="grey", outline="grey")
    pig_item = canvas.create_image(200, Pig_Y, image=pig_img)
    topPoles.clear()
    bottomPoles.clear()
    game()

def game():
    pig_fall()
    poles_move()
    collision_detection()
    score_level()
    create_poles()

Score = 0
score_text = canvas.create_text(35, 25, text=Score, font=('Helvetica', '30', 'bold'))

def score_level():
    global Score
    Score += 1
    canvas.itemconfig(score_text, text=Score)  
    window.after(2000, score_level)

window.bind('x', lambda event: restart_game())
game()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Standard debugging skills: `pig_bbox` is `None` when you probably expect a list or similar. Just keep pulling the thread, why is it so etc... [mre]

Comment: Does this help? `pig_bbox = canvas.bbox('pig_item')`

Comment: Note that `pig_item` inside `restart_game()` is a local variable, not the global one.

Comment: `canvas` has function to check `overlapping` elements - maybe it can be useful to detect collisions. Doc: [8.6. Methods on Canvas widgets](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is solution for part of problems. Maybe later I resolve other problems.

---

When you reset game you have to use global variables

```
def restart_game():
    global Score
    global lifeStatus
    global pig_item

    # ... rest ...
```

And this resolves problem with error message.

---

This function has another problem. It runs again `game()` which runs again `pig_fall()`, `poles_move()`,`create_poles()` which run new `after()` but they didn't remove previous `after()` - and now all run the same code twice and code runs 2 times faster. If you reset game again then it will run even faster.

Simple solutions: don't run again `game()`.

```
def restart_game():
    global Score
    global lifeStatus
    global pig_item
    
    Score = 0
    lifeStatus = "alive"
    
    canvas.delete("all")  # Clear the canvas
    canvas.create_image(200, 450, image=newfarm)
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 535, 500, 600, fill="grey", outline="grey")
    
    pig_item = canvas.create_image(200, Pig_Y, image=pig_img)
    
    topPoles.clear()
    bottomPoles.clear()

    #game()   # <--- don't run it again
```

---

Partial solution for detection collision:

Using `print()` I see it has empty lists `bottomPoles` and `topPoles` - so it can't detect collisions.

Problem is because it runs before `create_poles()` adds anything to these list. But real problem is because it doesn't use `after()` to run again and again to check collision periodically.

```
def collision_detection():
 
    # ... code ...

    window.after(10, collision_detection)
```

It detects collision but first collision gives error because it runs `you_died()` which run `canvas.delete("all")` to remove all objects but all `after()` still works and `collision_detection()` still runs `pig_bbox = canvas.bbox(pig_item)` which gives `pig_bbox = None` and later `if pig_bbox[3] > 525` means `if None[3] > 525` and this gives error. It would need to check `lifeStatus == "alive"` in every loop in  `collision_detection()` but I'm not sure if other functions which uses `after()` shouldn't also check `lifeStatus == "alive"`. Or it would need to stop all `after()` - and this needs to keep them in global variable (`after_id = after(..)`) and later use these variables to stop `after()`

Or it would need to run it in `if`

```
if lifeStatus == "alive"`:
    window.after(..)
```

---

Frankly, I would create it little different. I would remove `after()` from all functions and I would use `after()` to run `game()` in loop (like in `PyGame`)

```
def game():
    pig_fall()
    poles_move()
    collision_detection()
    score_level()
    create_poles()

    window.after(10, game)
```

and it would need to keep in global variable only one `after()` and stop only one `after()`.